# EDSDK Canon Get Full Resolution Live View Image

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, edsdk, canon-sdk

I want to Live view image with full resolution (6240/4148) live view without capture image because when i do normal live view Resolution (960/640) View image quality very bad i want to get full live view stream

Comment: Look into _DirectShow API_

Comment: I am using Canon EDSDK 13.10.20 with Canon 6D Mark II

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The live view only exists with lower resolution, that's simply how Canon has made it.

With such high resolutions you are asking for you'll also have problems with data transfer rates (=extremely low FPS)

Comment: Hello Johannes Bildstein Thanks for reply  i want to partial image on rectangle area it's possible or not , i want to get sequence by sequence rectangle partial area